# Aspx page not found on IIS hosted site but it exists on path

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have form which getting this problem. If I run same project using visual studio 2010 it runs perfect but I have published the same project on server it throws error

```
 `HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.`
```

This single page throws error other pages working fine.

**Local :**
[image]

**Server:**
[image]

**Server Environment:**

IIS 6.1
Windows Server 2008 R2

Any idea about this?

Comment: Your two different webservers have different resource paths: locally you're using `/` but the production server is `/SightsHPCTesting16/` - is that correct? Are you using any URL-routing?

Comment: /SightsHPCTesting16/ is just hosting application hosting alias. Other pages from same alias are working fine.

Comment: Have you checked whether page exists on server physically??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved by cleaning the Temporary ASP.NET Files because same name .aspx form is having master page included in it and new .aspx page doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Is ASP.NET installed in the server? If not, there will not be any appropriate handling of .aspx files. To install ASP.NET, you must run the following command, which varies depending on the CPU architecture and server.

**32-bit, ASP.NET 2.0 - 3.5**
    %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -i

**32-bit ASP.NET 4.0+**
    %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

**64-bit, ASP.NET 2.0 - 3.5**
    %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -i

**64-bit ASP.NET 4.0+**
    %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

If you still continue getting the error, I would recomend to browse to the page locally on an Browser within the server itself or open the IIS log (defaulted to %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC#\ folder). You will either get a 404.# locally or in the sc-substatus column in the IIS log will give us more information as to why IIS is responding a 404. Let me know if the command above helps or if you manage to get the sub-status for that 404.

I'll reformat this answer once I get to an actual laptop.

Comment: Actually, if you're getting the screen that he is getting, then ASP.NET is running (that's the "YSOD").  If not you would be seeing an IIS error page which looks quite different.  It's a little hard to tell as his screenshot cuts off the bottom, but if it didn't you would see a mention of which version of ASP.NET generated the page.